# How to see test coverage with Xcode5 bots?

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-bots

I use the [Continuous Integration in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html)

The UI is beautiful and easy to set up. I want to use it as our CI tool. However, it seems not to have a test coverage feature. It is a key feature for us. Is there a way to see test coverage on Xcode? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of.

[This blog post](http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-unit-testing/) talks about unit testing in XCode4, but much of it still applies to XCode5.  I thought the author did a good job of summarizing the current state of affairs.  Apple addressed the author's concern about CI with Bots, but nothing has changed as far as Coverage Analysis is concerned.

Comment: Thanks! OK. I'll try to check another CI service like Travis CI.